# Broke default easy_install on mac Python ... how do i fix it?

Tags: python, macos

I kind of deleted easy_install and I'm not sure how to re-install it:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

I'd like my default 2.7.5 mac python to work again.  Thanks guys!

I do have

```
./bin/easy_install-2.5
./bin/easy_install-2.6
./bin/easy_install-2.7
```

on my system.  Am I supposed to make a symlink or something to one of those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Taken from the [official setuptools documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions):*

Open the terminal and follow these steps:

- Download ez_setup.py and run it using the target Python version. The script will download the appropriate version and install it for you: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python`
- Note that you may need to invoke the command with superuser privileges to install to the system Python: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python`
- Alternatively, Setuptools may be installed to a user-local path: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python - --user`